# Src folder in android studio there isnt

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-activity, view

im newbie with android and android studio but iam some problem with the basicly configuration...

there arent a lot of folder in my project for example src, libs like attachment

i need src :D

can you help me ?
thanks a lot

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the view from Android to Project as mentioned in [this link](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio-androidview.html).

[image: Project view]

Then your `src` directory should be inside the app folder.

[image: src folder]

---

Everything that you have inside the `src` folder should be in the Android view by default though.